# Why is the graph of function behaving in a seemingly erratic fashion?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, indeterminate-forms

I was recently trying to plot the graph of the function $f(x)$. This function is defined as follows:

$
f(x) = \frac{\sin{3x} - 3\sin{x}}{(\pi - x)^3}
$

I first plotted the numerator ($A(x) = \sin{3x} - 3\sin{x}$) and the reciprocal of the denominator (B(x) = $\frac{1}{(\pi - x)^3}$) separately. Their graphs were as expected, with an asymptote in the latter: [image of the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vok2B.png).

However, when I later plotted the whole function, it showed [highly erratic behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdP9c.png) at $x \to \pi$.

The graph is available [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3z8takaeoa).

It can be seen that the function itself is indeterminate at $x = \pi$, but the other two functions ($A$ and $B$) I plotted seem to be quite well behaved at $x = \pi$. This made me wonder why does their product, $f$ behave in an oscillatory fashion. Is it because of the asymptote caused in $B$? Or is there any other reason?

I'd appreciate any insight into the matter.

Comment: It's just numerical error https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+%28sin%283x%29-3sin%28x%29%29%2F%28x-pi%29%5E3

Comment: Interestingly, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot%5B%28sin%283+x%29-3+sin%28x%29%29%2F%28π-x%29%5E3%2C%7Bx%2C3.14158%2C3.1416%7D%5D) plots it as if there is a vertical asymptote.

Comment: It looks to me to just be a "finite precision" kind of error.  The website presumably evaluates the function numerically when generating that graph rather than solving it analytically before evaluating it at various points.  So, when it looks at your function very close to $x=\pi$ it'll make small rounding errors that compound with each other problematically.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a graph of the function.
[image: graph 1]
The limit at $\pi$ is $-4$.

Here is a magnified graph.
[image: graph 2]
It looks like it is doing wild stuff near $\pi$.  But look
at the scale on the $y$-axis... All that wild stuff is within $0.0002$ of the true limit $-4$.

Comment: Yes. That's what was showing up on desmos as well. It was a bit difficult to explain why this behavior is observed.